# Return Bool if a specific value repeats

Tags: haskell

I'm currently doing a project for school about email identification but there is a certain part of the code that I have been stuck for quite a while, I've been trying to figure out how I could return `Bool` if a certain value would repeat.

This is my current code:

The idea is to build a function that searches if a certain value is repeated

```
repeated :: [Char] -> Bool
repeated [] = False
repeated [_] = False
repeated (x:xs) = if elem x xs then True else repeated xs
```

At this part of the code I don't know how to specify the value that I want to return Bool if it repeats

```
special :: [String] -> [String]
special x = filter (elem ['.','_']) (map repeated x)
```

the expected output was this:
special "penuts.."
`True`

Comment: How does `repeated` search for a "certain value" that "is repeated" when it only gets a list and not a value which it should look for? What is the purpose of `special`, what should it return?

Comment: repeated is a function that returns bool is a certain value repeats. I want to implement this function into the new function "special" so i can specify wich value i want to return Bool if it repeats

Comment: the input should be like: `special "butter" ` and if i specify that if the Character "t"repeats the output should be True

Comment: Unfortunately, the `repeated` you have defined here is not a suitable building block for the thing you want to make. You'll have to rethink your plan.

Comment: This is what i came up with: ```element _[] = False```
                                                                                                                                 ```element x (y : ys) = if x == y then True else element x ys```  but still, i don't know how to call it on the other function and specify on what value i want the function to return  Bool

Comment: Unrelated: `if e1 then True else e2` --> `e1 || e2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have a solution, and so I don't feel I'm ruining a good learning experience, here are some additional implementation ideas that you might enjoy.

If you want to check a single character's repeated-ness status, you could ask for just the copies of that character, and then check whether there's two (or more) of them.

```
repeats :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
repeats a as = case filter (a==) as of
    _:_:_ -> True
    _ -> False
```

However, this might be less efficient if you have many `repeats` queries you want to make. If that's so, you may want to preprocess the list, paying some up-front cost to make future queries faster. One way would be to count each of the elements.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

count :: Ord a => [a] -> M.Map a Int
count as = M.fromListWith (+) [(a, 1) | a <- as]
```

Given counts, it's easy to check whether a given character repeats.

```
repeats' :: Ord a => a -> M.Map a Int -> Bool
repeats' a as = M.findWithDefault 0 a as >= 2
```

For example, to check multiple characters for repetition at once, you might write:

```
multirepeats :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
multirepeats needle haystack = or [repeats' a as | a <- needle] where
    as = count haystack
```

Giving the result of the call to `count` a name in a `where` block means it will be computed just once in each call to `multirepeats` (at least, when using GHC).

If you wanted to check whether there is *any* repeating character, you could reuse `count` like this:

```
anyRepeats :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
anyRepeats = any (>=2) . count
```

Or, you could do this directly with list-based operations if you sort first:

```
import Data.List

anyRepeats' :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
anyRepeats' as = not $ null [() | _:_:_ <- group (sort as)]
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me more ways to solve it, and it's always a plesure to learn more from experts like you in this community, am new to it but am enjoying each second.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing my function, i came across with the solution

```
element :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Bool
element _[] = False
element x (y : ys) = if x == y then elem x ys else element x ys
```

if the specific value repeats, the boolean value output should be True:

```
element '.'"ban.nan."
True
```

Comment: A more general version of this function, `elem`, already exists.

Comment: am still new to haskell, and i been trying to use elem to speficy the value that i want to filter if the boolean is True

Comment: i wanted to filter some character's like  '.', '_','@' that if they would repeat the function should return True

Comment: Ah, I missed that you were calling `elem` from `element`.

Answer (score 0):

i also got my desire solution output:

```
repeatedLocal :: [Char] -> Bool
repeatedLocal [] = False
repeatedLocal [_] = False
repeatedLocal (x:xs) = if elem x ['.', '_'] then True else repeated xs
```

Comment: This seems to have different behavior from your previous solution. For example, `repeatedLocal ".a"` is `True` but `element '.' ".a"` is `False`.

Comment: i changed the last section
``repeatedLocal (x:xs) = if elem x ['.', '_'] then elem x xs else repeatedLocal xs``

Comment: Then `repeatedLocal "_.."` is `False` but `element '.' "_.."` is `True`.